# Gatsby Image - possible get rid of empty div with padding?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm using a [masonry system](https://codesandbox.io/s/masonry-hook-attempt-bd7ci?file=/src/App.js) that doesn't work with Gatsby Image but works fine with regular jpgs and gifs.

I'm 99% sure it's because of this empty div with padding that gets inserted when I use Gatsby's `<Img>`, the second line here:

```
<div class="gatsby-image-wrapper">
<div aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 68%;"></div>
<picture><source srcset="...
...
```

when I delete that in the inspector view the masonry works fine. Is there a way to omit that from being inserted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're confident it's ok to remove that `div`, try setting `display: none` to it:

```css
.gatsby-image-wrapper > div[aria-hidden="true"] {
  display: none;
}
```

`display: none` will basically remove the div from the page layout & may solve your issue.

Comment: this worked, thank you!! this + adding `imgStyle={{ position: "static" }}` to the Img makes the masonry work.